# Why does PyDev flag an import error but the code works?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pydev

Pillow has been added to the project. Here's the code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter, ImageDraw, ImageFont
im = Image.open("someImage.jpg")
print(im.width, im.height, im.mode, im.format)  # Display
im.show(im)
```

Pillow is imported and the code runs fine, but PyDev gives the error:

```
Unresolved import: Image
――――――――――――――――――――
Image Found at: foo

from PIL import Image, ImageFilter, ImageDraw, ImageFont
```

[image]

If I comment out the import statement, I get a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ImagePractice\foo.py", line 2, in <module>
    im = Image.open("someImage.jpg")
NameError: name 'Image' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

@nicomp if you add `PIL` to the `Forced Builtins` in the interpreter you're using, does it work? (see: https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html for more details)